# How to get the correct time in UTC timestamp?

Tags: javascript, timestamp, unix-timestamp

I am using the UTC timestamp to get the 5 minutes ahead of current time stamp but infact i am getting the the timestamp as 60 minutes before current timestamp.

```
function storevalue(){
    var Date1= new Date();
    var Time1=Date1.toUTCString().slice(0, -4);
            alert(Date1);

}
```

Suppose the current timestamp is (Mon, 24 Jun 2019 14:10:00) and the time stamp i want is (Mon, 24 Jun 2019 14:15:00) i.e 5 minutes ahead of current time stamp but the actual outcome i am getting is (Mon, 24 Jun 2019 13:10:00) i.e 60 minutes behind current timestamp.

Comment: I guess you're in a timezone that's UTC+1. Your local time (`new Date()`) will always be different to UTC.

Comment: the best thing to do is used either moment or date-fns when working with dates

Comment: Any idea about how to add 60 mins to this timestamp?

Comment: @user5891930 why do you want to *add* 60 minutes, instead of taking *the local time*?